# can I change uname?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Discovery Studio Visualizer but the precompiled binary checks the system for OS version. When it finds that I am not running RHEL, the installer exits.

Is there a way to change or trick programs that call uname into displaying different info?

Comment: You would need to either recompile the kernel (and give it a different name) or recompile the DSV so it does not check, or see how DSV checks your OS.Run the script from here - http://accelrys.com/products/collaborative-science/biovia-discovery-studio/requirements/technical-requirements-400-libraries.html and contact upstream.

Comment: Ive tried upstream contact they arent geting back to me

Comment: Is there some reason not to run Centos then ? It is difficult to know how they are perfroming OS detection. You could edit /etc/issue perhaps?

Comment: are you sure it checks uname? and not  /etc/lsb-release?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot customize `uname`'s output, but you can spoof the installer by making the system run a custom script instead of the "real" `/bin/uname`.

First you'll need to check the exact command the installer is running to check your system's information; in this example for the sake of easiness I'll pretend that an executable `~/tmp/check` is running `uname -n` and that the output of `uname -n` should be `ubuntu` in order for `~/tmp/check` to print "Passed!".

`~/tmp/check`'s source (this of course is not relevant, and is just to showcase what the test executable does):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 32

int main(void) {
    FILE* output = popen("/bin/uname -n", "r");
    char expected[] = "ubuntu";
    char hostname[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    fgets(hostname, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, output);
    pclose(output);
    if(hostname[strlen(hostname) - 1] == '\n')
        hostname[strlen(hostname) - 1] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(expected, hostname) == 0) {
        printf("Passed!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ uname -n
debian
user@debian:~/tmp$ ./check
user@debian:~/tmp$
```

It's easy to track the exact command run by the executable using `strace`:

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ strace -f ./check 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep execve
execve("./check", ["./check"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
[pid 13122] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/uname -n"], [/* 34 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid 13122] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid 13123] execve("/bin/uname", ["/bin/uname", "-n"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
```

So to get around this one should make `uname -n` output `ubuntu`: the easiest solution would be to just move `/bin/uname` and to create a symbolic link `/bin/uname` linking to a custom script (which will ignore any argument and just output `ubuntu`):

`cat ~/tmp/spoofer.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo ubuntu
exit 0
```

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ sudo mv /bin/uname /bin/uname1
user@debian:~/tmp$ sudo ln -s ~/tmp/spoofer.sh /bin/uname
```

Let's see if that worked:

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ uname -n
ubuntu
user@debian:~/tmp$ ./check
Passed!
user@debian:~/tmp$
```

Bingo! (remember to remove `/bin/uname` and to move `/bin/uname1` back to `/bin/uname` afterwards: `sudo rm /bin/uname && sudo mv /bin/uname1 /bin/uname`)

Answer (score 1):

alias uname 'uname \!* | sed s/Ubuntu/RHEL/'

This is c-shell format alias, you might have to change it a bit based on what shell you are using.